# How to use different columns to plot different color properties (hue, value, saturation) with geopandas?

Tags: python, colors, geopandas

I'm plotting a map using `geopandas`, using one of the columns as a visual variable for coloring. I have used so far the following code:

```py
gdf.plot(ax=ax, column='Data_1', legend=True, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap=cmap).
```

I would like to use another column to show more data, specifically use 'Data_1' for hue, and 'Data_2' for color saturation/value. Is it possible?

Comment: matplotlib colors are RGBA, so this seems like a tall order. What kind of data are we talking about here?

Comment: Actually using one data column for "RGB", and the second column for "A" would be ok as well! I now loaded the data into QGIS, and used their function color_rgba to encode the data into a new column with the string of RGBA values for displaying colors - I don't think it's that easy in python though. The data are shapefiles (polygons) with certain attributes.

Comment: It doesn't matter that they are polygons, and it's already clear they have attributes. What are those attributes like? Categorical data? Ordinal data? Floating point numbers?

Comment: oh, I see. They are floating point numbers